# Warning: Prop `id` did not match. shown when using the CreatableSelect in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-select

*Error Message From Console*

[image of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXG09.png)

I use the CreatableSelect component from the react-select module to create my search bar.

this is my code

```
<CreatableSelect
   id={"search-bar"}
   defaultValue={{
      label: wordEntered || "Enter your search keyword",
   }}
   options={[
      ...filteredData.map((item) => {
         return {
            value: item,
            label: item.name,
         }
      })
   ]}
   components={{
      DropdownIndicator: () => null,
      IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
      NoOptionsMessage: () => (
         <span className={"mx-2"}>
            Press Enter to Search for {wordEntered}
         </span>
      ),
   }}

   onInputChange={(value) => {
      setWordEntered(value)
   }}
   onChange={(value) => {
      goToSearch(value.value)
   }}
   getOptionLabel={(option) => {
      return (
         <>
            {wordEntered && wordEntered.length > 0 && <span>
               Search for {option.value}
            </span>}
            {(!wordEntered || !wordEntered.length) && <span>
               Enter your search keyword
            </span>}
         </>
      )
   }}
/>
```

My Main Issue is that I have no idea why there is a change in the value between server and client.

A description to the issue might help me solve it, thank you in adv. :)

I was expecting a problem with the assignable id prop however when I tried to statically type it, and call it "search-bar" that didn't work.